# Best method to reset Android device?

Tags: factory-reset, huawei

I own a Huawei P9 EVA-AL00 (bought in China) on Android 7 with no root. Last time I reset my device, some photos were still left.

So, what is the best way to reset an Android device?

I'm not worried about security, privacy and encryption, but I do want all junk files, photos etc. to be removed from the device.

I know the 2 methods to reset - through recovery and settings, but is there a better way? For example, can you reset through Android Debug Bridge?

Thanks,

George

Comment: Safe way is to encrypt your phone and factory reset to ensure that files on your device are not accessible to any one

Answer (score 0):

While both methods (factory-reset through settings and through recovery) should have the very same effect, both also usually leave the SD cards (internal and external) alone. So if you really want to clear *all* things up, you should "wipe" those as well. Some devices/ROMs offer to include the cards in factory reset, with others you'll have to do that manually – either by deleting all files, or by going to *Settings › Storage* and chosing to format them.

If you were "worried about security, privacy and encryption", I'd instead recommend you a tool to "[securely wipe](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_datawipe#group_457)" all partitions, i.e. overwrite everything with garbage.